# Как добавить любую информацию на страницу пользователя в админке WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

Появилась задача отобразить на странице пользователя в админке Wordpress некоторую информацию. Есть ли какой-то крючок, что бы добавить сюда что-нибудь? А так же можно ли как-то узнать id пользователя, страница которого открыта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Узнал, что для добавления на страницу можно использовать
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'profile_page_footer' );

Осталось понять как узнать id пользователя, страницу которого мы посещаем.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код. Исправьте поля под ваши нужды и добавьте код в `functions.php` вашей темы.

```
/**
 * Add extra fields to user profile.
 *
 * @param WP_User $user WP_User object.
 */
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Дополнительная информация профиля', 'my-lang-domain' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="phone"><?php esc_html_e( 'Телефон', 'my-lang-domain' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input
                        type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
                        value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'phone', true ) ); ?>"
                        class="regular-text"/><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="manager"><?php _e( 'Личный менеджер', 'my-lang-domain' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="manager" id="manager" style="width: 25em;">
                    <?php
                    $selected   = esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'manager', true ) );
                    $users      = get_users();
                    $options    = array();
                    $options[0] = 'Выберите менеджера&hellip;';
                    foreach ( $users as $a_user ) {
                        $options[ $a_user->ID ] = $a_user->display_name;
                    }
                    foreach ( $options as $option_key => $option_value ) :
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option_key ); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $option_key, true ); ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $option_value ); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

/**
 * Save extra fields in user profile.
 *
 * @param int $user_id User ID.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = true;
    if ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
        $result = $result && update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', wc_clean( $_POST['phone'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['manager'] ) ) {
        $result = $result && update_user_meta( $user_id, 'manager', wc_clean( $_POST['manager'] ) );
    }

    return $result;
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
```